# Есть ли в JavaME библиотеки для работы с GPS?

Tags: java, gps

Есть ли в JavaME библиотеки для работы с GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть. Например, [JSR 179](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/) (+ [JSR 179 spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=179)). Она покрывает aGPS, так и полноценную GPS.

**UPD**

Да, если GPS-устройство внешнее, то можно по блютусу через JSR-82 подключаться